# Trying to install a 3-way switch but don't understand the colors of my wires

Tags: electrical, switch

I'm trying to connect a 3-way switch, but don't understand the colors of my wires.

On one side I have 1 black, 1 white and 1 red; while on the other side, I have 2 red and 1 white, no black.

How is this supposed to work??

Comment: We are going to need much more info than *on one side and on the other side*. How to ask a good question  https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include pictures of the existing switch, the new switch, and the inside of the box showing the wiring there. That will make it much easier for others to understand you since you're not up on all the lingo yet.

Comment: Sides are irrelevant, every switch puts the screws in different places.  Colors are also irrelevant, as they are different in every circuit :( You need to identify the two travelers and the common.  Hint:both travelers are in the same cable!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  And mark the travelers with yellow tape for easy identification in the future. I've been a member for a year and wish I had a dime for each time I heard you mention that.... and I've done it ever since..  stay safe.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  OK, yes, this is an OT comment, but I can't resist (pun intended) to say how much your comment reminds me of Star Trek Borg:  Resistance is futile, death is irrelevant, individuality is irrelevant, freedom is irrelevant.  I'm obviously a Trekkie.   Yes, moderators I know, this isn't a chat room, so I'll delete it in a bit.

Comment: There's only one way that this could meet code with regard to balancing currents in a cable or conduit, but you're still left guessing between the two reds at one of the switch locatons.